# Stop vs. Cancel Flink Job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have several Flink (1.5) jobs running in production.
Most of them uses Kafka 0.8.2.2 as the Source (we are working hard to upgrade Kafka, but that's another story).

Some of our jobs are using Flink session windows mechanism and some of them not (simple jobs that only map/filtering events).
In addition, some jobs are using AsyncIO to enrich events from an external database.

From time to time we find bugs or small features that we want to add for those existing jobs.

To prevent dataloss we `cancel` the relevant job (with `savepoint`), deploy the new updated job and run it again from last `savepoint`.

The problem is that most of the time we are getting exceptions while trying to run from last `savepoint` which is make sense, since we change the job code and the `savepoint` can't be loaded into memory, right?

The thing is that we **can** afford delays (we will close gaps later on) but we **cannot** afford dataloss.

I [saw](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/ops/cli.html#examples) the `stop` CLI operation which look promising, because it should do it gracefully.

- What are the supported Flink Sources for the graceful `stop` operation? is there Kafka version that supports that? is the Sink type also relevant? (Bucketing Sink might want to finish upload to S3?)
- Does the `stop` command support jobs that are using windows? if so, how does it behave in session windows?
- What is the best practice updating existing/running Flink job without loosing data?

**EDIT:** sometimes we see it in the the `cancel` command as well (exception) - due to timeout of AsyncIO:

```
java.lang.Exception: An async function call terminated with an exception. Failing the AsyncWaitOperator.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.Emitter.output(Emitter.java:137)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.Emitter.run(Emitter.java:85)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Async function call has timed out.
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.queue.StreamRecordQueueEntry.get(StreamRecordQueueEntry.java:68)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.Emitter.output(Emitter.java:129)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Async function call has timed out.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.async.AsyncWaitOperator$1.onProcessingTime(AsyncWaitOperator.java:212)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SystemProcessingTimeService$TriggerTask.run(SystemProcessingTimeService.java:281)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: What kind of exceptions?

Comment: About changing your job code and using "old" savepoint data you can use - [assigning opertor id](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/ops/state/savepoints.html#assigning-operator-ids)